# Error on adding PRIMARY KEY to existing table

Tags: mariadb, primary-key

I'm trying to alter a previously created table on MariaDB 10.4.21 and I'm getting the following error:

```
Import failed with: 'Incorrect index name 'pk_i_id''
```

The table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS /*TABLE_PREFIX*/t_mmessenger_recipients (
    message_id INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    recipient_id INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    readOn DATETIME,
    hidden BOOL DEFAULT FALSE,
    CONSTRAINT `fk_/*TABLE_PREFIX*/t_mmessenger_recipients_message` FOREIGN KEY(`message_id`) REFERENCES /*TABLE_PREFIX*/t_mmessenger_message(`id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE,
    PRIMARY KEY (`message_id`, `recipient_id`)
) ENGINE = InnoDB DEFAULT CHARACTER SET 'UTF8' COLLATE 'UTF8_GENERAL_CI';
```

The alter that generates the error (*line 4*):

```
ALTER TABLE /*TABLE_PREFIX*/t_mmessenger_recipients ADD `pk_i_id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT UNIQUE FIRST;
ALTER TABLE /*TABLE_PREFIX*/t_mmessenger_recipients DROP FOREIGN KEY `fk_/*TABLE_PREFIX*/t_mmessenger_recipients_message`;
ALTER TABLE /*TABLE_PREFIX*/t_mmessenger_recipients DROP PRIMARY KEY;
ALTER TABLE /*TABLE_PREFIX*/t_mmessenger_recipients ADD PRIMARY KEY (`pk_i_id`);
ALTER TABLE /*TABLE_PREFIX*/t_mmessenger_recipients ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_/*TABLE_PREFIX*/t_mmessenger_recipients_message`
    FOREIGN KEY(`message_id`)
    REFERENCES /*TABLE_PREFIX*/t_mmessenger_message(`id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

This seems to happen only on MariaDB, as on MySQL 5.7 it worked fine.

Comment: There's no column named `pk_i_id`. The parentheses are supposed to contain a list of columns in the key, not the name of the key.

Comment: Which columns should be in the new primary key?

Comment: The `ADD` should be getting an error because `AUTO_INCREMENT` has to be the primary key, so you need to remove the old primary key first.

Comment: So should I run the `ALTER TABLE /*TABLE_PREFIX*/t_mmessenger_recipients DROP PRIMARY KEY;` before the ADD `pk_i_id` column?
Because doing this returns another error. And why does it act up only on MariaDB 10.4 and not on MySQL 5.7?

Comment: I was wrong, it's not required to be the primary key.

Comment: Sadly it's as I thought, a MariaDB 10.4 bug: https://jira.mariadb.org/plugins/servlet/mobile#issue/MDEV-19598